# How to show these numbers in tabular format?

Tags: php

This code is giving the following output, I want to show these numbers in table is there any way to do this? and why it is not showing the numbers in proper format like why 53 is not exactly below  40 and others also not showing in proper order?

```
<?php

$arr = array();

for ($i=1;$i<82;$i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

shuffle($arr);
$lines = array_chunk($arr, 9);
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
   $lines[$key] = implode("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp", $line);
}
echo implode("<br>", $lines);
?>
```

Output

```
73   40   79   1   43   7   76   44   18
6   53   45   55   71   20   80   66   74
69   51   52   65   22   63   59   50   54
29   33   23   49   77   24   61   60   58
8   81   30   15   26   32   16   47   31
17   39   4   35   27   11   5   25   68
2   34   72   42   75   46   48   3   38
14   28   37   62   10   78   12   56   13
41   21   19   36   9   64   67   57   70
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use tables or CSS. You can use a `<pre>` tag then use some tabs and newlines

```
<pre>
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($i=1;$i<82;$i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

shuffle($arr);
$lines = array_chunk($arr, 9);
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
   $lines[$key] = implode("\t", $line);
}
echo implode("\n", $lines);
?>
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/372318)**

Note: I didn't really care about your logic for creating those lines while answering this question since its only about formatting. You can trim down some code too.

**Output**

```
22  16  66  79  8   41  47  2   80
29  38  76  18  40  46  73  34  45
31  3   62  68  14  33  20  72  67
78  44  42  30  51  77  36  25  48
64  70  21  15  19  9   56  50  65
37  27  4   1   35  74  75  52  32
81  23  10  28  26  59  7   54  11
6   63  5   39  53  12  24  60  49
71  55  17  13  61  69  43  57  58
```

Now with slightly better code

```
<pre>
<?php
$numbers=range(1,81);
shuffle($numbers);
$c=0;
foreach($numbers as $n)
{
    if($c%9==0)echo "\n";
    echo $n."\t";
    $c++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

modify your code like this:

```
<?php

$arr = array();

for ($i=1;$i<82;$i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

shuffle($arr);
$lines = array_chunk($arr, 9);
echo '<table>';
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
   echo '<tr><td align="right">';
   echo $lines[$key] = implode('</td><td align="right">', $line);
   echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

**Output**

```
57  41  48  17  73  76  7   78  12
69  61  39  80  24  58  45  11  70
47  65  33  21  38  4   19  13  46
59  52  63  14  25  3   30  28  77
50  40  68  6   2   29  20  66  26
72  74  34  75  15  36  71  10  60
55  53  1   16  23  42  51  35  62
44  32  43  64  18  8   54  49  5
81  27  31  67  37  22  79  56  9
```

Comment: may i suggest `<td align="right">` for a nicer display?

Comment: your code print nothing.check. you miss some thing.

Comment: check modified answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

$arr = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 82; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

shuffle($arr);
$lines = array_chunk($arr, 9);

echo "<table>";

foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($line); $i++) {
        echo "<td align='right'>" . $line[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Your Out put

[image]